# C++ program out of memory

Tags: c++, memory, crash

First of all I am really sorry, but I have no clue where is the error in my program, I'we been through it hundred times but I just can't find it.
When I was debugging in VB2010 I was getting access validation error, so there must be a function that is taking memory from some place where it's not allowed. Program is made to take some data from database, sort it and return it to output.txt.
It is Latin-Croatian dictionary. Anyway please help.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void ascii_convert(int);
void string_compare(string);
void word_sort(int a,string inp);
string word1=0;
string word2=0;
string word3=0;
string upis;
string word[30] = {};
int match=0;
int input=0;
int broj_rijeci = 0;

int main()
{
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("database.txt");            //loading database.txt
  int count = 0; 
  if (myfile.is_open()){
  while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
  if(line.at(0) == '['){                       //get's the number of words in database..
     int i = line.length()-1;                  //...that is the first line of databse
     int brojac = 0;
     while(line.at(i) != line.at(0)){
        input = line.at(i);
        ascii_convert(input);
        broj_rijeci = broj_rijeci + input*static_cast<int>(pow(static_cast<double>(10),brojac));
        i--;
        brojac++;
    }
  }
  if(line.at(0) != '['){
     for(int i = 0; line.at(i)!=' ' ;i++){
        word[count] = word[count] + line.at(i);
       }
     count++;   
    }
}
myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

for(int i = 0; i<broj_rijeci ;i++) cout<<word[i]<<endl;    
cin>>upis;
string_compare(upis);  //after this line I will put the output as output.txt
system("pause");      
return 0;
}

void string_compare(string){
int len1 = upis.length();   
int len;
for(int i = 0; i < broj_rijeci; i++){
 int len2 = word[i].length();
 if (len1<len2) len = len1;
 else len = len2;
 for(int y = 0; y < len; y++){
     if(upis.at(y) == word[i].at(y)) match++;          
    }
    word_sort(match,word[i]);  
  }
}
void word_sort(int a,string inp){
    int match1 = 0;
    int len1 = upis.length();   
    int len;
    for(int i = 0; i < broj_rijeci; i++){
        int len2 = word1.length();
        if (len1<len2) len = len1;
        else len = len2;
        for(int y = 0; y < len; y++){
            if(upis.at(y) == word1.at(y)) match1++;          
        }  
    }
    if(a>match1){
     word3 = word2;
     word2 = word1;
     word1 = inp; 
    }else{
      int match1 = 0;
        int len1 = upis.length();   
        int len;
        for(int i = 0; i < broj_rijeci; i++){
            int len2 = word2.length();
            if (len1<len2) len = len1;
            else len = len2;
            for(int y = 0; y < len; y++){
                if(upis.at(y) == word2.at(y)) match1++;          
            }  
        }
       if(a>match1){
         word3 = word2;
         word2 = inp;   
        }else{
            int match1 = 0;
            int len1 = upis.length();   
            int len;
            for(int i = 0; i < broj_rijeci; i++){
                int len2 = word3.length();
                if (len1<len2) len = len1;
                else len = len2;
                for(int y = 0; y < len; y++){
                    if(upis.at(y) == word3.at(y)) match1++;          
                }     
            }
            if(a>match1) word3 = inp;
        }  
    }
}

void ascii_convert(int){         //function for converting variable "input"  
if(input == 48){                //from ascii to decimal numbers
    input = 0;
}
if(input == 49){
    input = 1;
}
if(input == 50){
    input = 2;
}
if(input == 51){
    input = 3;
}
if(input == 52){
    input = 4;
}
if(input == 53){
    input = 5;
}
if(input == 54){
    input = 6;
}
if(input == 55){
    input = 7;
}
if(input == 56){
    input = 8;
}
if(input == 57){
    input = 9;
 }         
}
```

And this is my "database.txt":

```
[4]
terra ae f zemlja
amica ae f prijateljica
puela ae f djevojcica
nauta ae m mornar
```

Thank you for support

Comment: Your `ascii_converter` function will have no effect (and also can be written in one line if you figure out the relationship between the input and output values).

Comment: @sftrabbit: It'll work fine, unfortunately.  `input` is global.

Comment: @CHao Oh. Interesting that they pass `input` to the unnamed parameter...

Comment: @sftrabbit: Yeah, that function seems quite conflicted about whether it wants to take arguments or mess with globals.  :P

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind`? It's one of the best tools for debugging memory management issues.

Answer (score 2):

First, all of these have to be fixed

```
string word1=0;
string word2=0;
string word3=0;
```

These are initializing `string` objects to what is being interpreted as converted NULL pointers. Not good. Frankly I'm shocked your program even finishes initializing globals before `main()`, because it certainly doesn't on my toolchain.

Next, this is using an index *far* outside its array's declared size:

```
for(int i = 0; i<broj_rijeci ;i++) cout<<word[i]<<endl;
```

With the given input file and utilizing *your* load algorithm, `broj_rijeci` is calculated as 133, only 94 entries longer than the size of `word[]`. In short, your calculation of that variable is flat-wrong, or the array is *way* undersized. Either way, its **undefined behavior**. I'm leaning toward the former of those (the load algorithm is wrong). But without *precise* information of the purpose of each entity on each line, there isn't much more input I can foster on that regard.

Apart from that, this is littered with programming inconstancy and poor practices. Functions passed parameters only to modify globals of the parameter passed is just the tip of the iceberg.

**Croatian-English Cheat Sheet**

For interested parties that want to expand that algorithm (or at least try and make sense of what it is trying to do):

- brojač = counter
- broj = number or size
- riječi = words
- ae = generator